# Right Column bottom on all mobile devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm just starting on bootstrap and trying to understand how the grid works exactly

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="leftContainer  col-md-6">
 A
 </div>
  <div class="rightContainer  col-md-6">
 B
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.leftcontainer{
  float:left;
}

.rightcontainer{
  float:right;
}
```

I don't want scroll bar at the bottom on the mobile devices. My output is of this format on mobile

```
A

                    B
```

Instead I want

```
A

B
```

but `A   B` on desktop

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It's not clear to us what you want for mobile and what you want for desktop.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: sorry updated the question, my bad

Comment: A [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/97DO0vPW0z) with the given code shows exactly what you specify. What problem are you really facing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="leftContainer col-xs-12 col-md-6">
 A
 </div>
  <div class="rightContainer col-xs-12 col-md-6">
 B
 </div>
</div>
```

and remove your CSS. You don't need to add the floats to any of this.

Also, please read up on the grid system in the Bootstrap documentation. It has whatever you need. http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Thanks, it works fine. But on the desktop if I remove float:right there is no gap between left and right columns. How do I add space in between?

Comment: Technically you would have no space there even with floats (FYI your classnames in the style sheet are lower-cased while in the HTML they aren't). One way to give a space is to make both divs a width of 49% and then float left and right, respectively.